# Rs.exe creating a blank PDF

Tags: reporting-services, rs.exe

I am trying to use RS.exe to create a PDF extract of one of our SSRS reports. This works successfully when running the executable for certain sets of data but then not for others. Below is the line we are using. Any ideas as to why this would create a blank PDF (but still has size to it - 3 pages get created in the PDF which is expected BUT they are all blank).

Call rs.exe  -i RSutility.rss  -s "localhost/ReportServer"  -v  REPORTSERVER_FOLDER="/Reports/Test"  -v  USERIDVALUE="100" -v  GROUPNAMEVALUE="SUBSET1"  -V  FILENAME="D:\TEST_1.pdf"   -t  -v FORMAT="PDF"  -e  Exec2005

Looking for advice on things to try

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.